# Jwplayer Error event and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, jwplayer7

I am trying to log all the jwplayer error events to google analytics i.e,

```
jwplayer().on('error', function(event) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'JW Player Events', 'Errors', 'event.message');
});
```

I am getting the hits on my analytics when the error is triggered and on which page, but I am having hard time in sending the error information (video not found or missing meta data, etc..). And all i can see is

```
Event Label 
event.message
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Try it without the single quotes, so just `event.message` for the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes from the label so it's

```
ga('send', 'event', 'JW Player Events', 'Errors', event.message);
```